# How to randperm k first elements of vector with its size N

Tags: matlab, permutation

I am using randperm to random permutation the element in vector. However, I have a problem that is I have a vector with its size N, and I want only random permutation k first elements in that vector, while N-k element is no change. How to do it by matlab code?

For example:

```
A = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
% N=10 array length; d=4 number of element equal to 1 in the first k elements, k=7
```

Desired output:

```
A_randperm=[0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
% Random permutation elements of 1st to 7th, 8th to 10th elements stay the same
```

This is my code

```
d=4;
N=10;
k=7;
column = [ones(1,d) zeros(1,N-d)];% create random vector without permutation

% Random permutation
....
```

Comment: `A(1:k) = A(randperm(k));`

Comment: @JandeGier post as answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment:

```
A(1:k) = A(randperm(k));
```

does the job.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on @JanDeGier's solution:

```
x = 1:10;
k = 7;

x = [x(randperm(k)) x(k+1:end)];
```